# DAX Running Total and 75% Complete Date

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I would like to forecast the month (as a date) at which 75% of the account ceilings will be spent.  Here are three very generic example tables for a much more complicated dataset/scenario, but I think a simple solution here will get me on my way.  I will actually be using weeks, but months is simpler for this example.

[image]   [image]

[image]

So, I need a cumulative, or running total of Cost which I believe is:

```
Cumulative Cost:=Calculate(Sum(Cost[Cost],filter(all(Months[Month],Months[Month]<=max(Months[Month])))
```

But then I'm stuck on finding the `Month` at which: `[Cumulative Cost]>=.75*[Ceiling]`

I will display the date for each Account in my Power Pivot Table.  Any ideas?

I'm using Power Pivot in Excel 2016

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a calculated column for cumulative cost on your `Cost` table as follows:

```
Cumulative Cost = CALCULATE(SUM(Cost[Cost]),
                            FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Cost, Cost[Account]),
                                   Cost[Month] <= EARLIER(Cost[Month])))
```

Once you have that, your 75% complete date can be calculated using a minimum function:

```
75% Complete Date = MINX(FILTER(Cost, Cost[Cumulative Cost] >= 0.75*Accounts[Ceiling]),
                         Cost[Month])
```

This finds the minimal date where the cumulative cost is greater than 75% of the ceiling.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try.  Do I have to make a calculated column?  Reason I ask is that my actual data is more complicated.  I have three separate tables with cost that need to be summed together, so the calculated column would be three fold, and then I don't know if the cumulative will still work.  Also, my understanding is that calculated columns will bog down my file with constant re-calculations.  Anyhow, I'll see if I can do something similar to what suggested.  Thanks

Comment: To elaborate, here is how I currently sum Cost in my real data:  `Total CPFF:=Sum(Actual_Hours[Total CPFF Cost])+sum(Forecast_Hours[Total CPFF Cost])+sum(Invoice_Hours[Total CPFF Cost])+sum(Travel_Data[Cost + MH + G&A])'

Comment: It's actually four tables (not three):  Actual Hours, Forecast Hours, Invoice Hours, and Travel_Data.  So, I'd have to put a calculated column in each one and sort of "join" them

Comment: @Brian Calculated columns are only computed once (when the data is loaded). It's measures that calculate dynamically. If you need help putting together logic for multiple tables, I'd suggest creating a new question with a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than trying to change the scope of what you are asking here.

Comment: I understand.  I was hoping there'd be a solution using measures, which I'd be able to make work in my situation.  Some real life scenarios are too hard to explain in a question.

Comment: @Brian I'm pretty sure there is a solution using measures, but I can only give answers to the stated question. If you want to specify additional context in a new question I can probably give it a look as long as it has a minimal complete verifiable example to work from.

Comment: Should I edit/fix this question or start all over with new?

Comment: @Brian I'd suggest accepting this one as answered and creating a new one where you describe your problem more fully.

Comment: Thank you, Alexis.  Here is my new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372758/dax-power-pivot-calculate-75-expended-date-from-cumulative-total