# DAX/Power Pivot: Calculate 75% Expended Date from Cumulative Total

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have three tables that contain cost:  Forecasted Cost, Actual Costs, Invoiced Costs.  Each has an "EAC Filter" column for a Y/N of whether to include the cost in an Estimate at Completion, which automatically changes over time and/or as data is added.  Here are examples:

[image] [image] [image]

EAC from the three tables can be calculated as follows:

```
Total Cost = Sum(Forecast[Cost])+Sum(Actual[Cost])+Sum(Invoice[Cost])
EAC = Calculate([Total Cost],EAC_Filter[EAC Filter]="Y")
```

I have a budget at the "Account" level, which could also be rolled up to a "Dept" level budget.

[image] [image] [image]

I need a measure for my Power Pivot table which will display the week at which costs have exceeded, or are forecasted to exceed 75% of the budget, using some sort of a cumulative cost, combined with the max week where cumulative cost >= .75 * Budget.

The weeks are numbered through the year as follows:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like your formula will deliver either a past week which is easy to identify, or a future week which is pretty hard to identify.  In order to forecast the future week in question, you need to calculate a burn rate--- is this the most recent burn rate or another figure?

Comment: Are you referring to my EAC formula?  That is used to determine total cost at the last week.  I'm not sure if it will be related to my 75% solution, but I provided it as an example of how I'm currently using the data.  As for a burn rate, that's not really the direction I want to go, if I can avoid.  I'd like to use my forecast to do that.  Also, this is all dummy data.

Thanks

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have said "cumulative EAC" in my question.  Will change that now.

Comment: @elliotsvensson I think the `Forecast` table takes care or the future week issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `EAC` measure which sums the cost per week,

```
EAC = CALCULATE(SUM(Forcast[Cost]) + SUM(Acutal[Cost]) + SUM(Invoice[Cost]),
                EAC_Filter[EAC Filter] = "Y")
```

You can create a `Cumulative Cost` measure as follows:

```
Cumulative Cost = CALCULATE([EAC],
                      FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Week] <= MAX('Calendar'[Week])))
```

Using this, we can create a measure that predicts the week the cost exceeds 75% of the budget:

```
75% Week = MINX(FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), [Cumulative Cost] > 0.75 * SUM(Budget[Budget])),
               'Calendar'[Week])
```

---

Here's what the relationships structure looks like:

[image: Relationships]

Comment: Thank you very much!  That approach is working.  I appreciate your time answering these questions.  I do have an issue in the pivot table where the 75% Date is causing all Accounts to be repeated for each Department, even though they don't all belong in all Departments, and then displaying the minimum date for each of those otherwise blank pivot table rows.  Of course, I'm translating my real data into the dummy data, but I'm hoping I'll be able to figure that part out.  You certainly have me in the right direction now.  Thanks!

Comment: I know this is kind of a new question, but it's related to your solution.  How do I calculate the one week just before the "75% Week?"  Is there like an 'Earlier' or 'Before' syntax I can use?  I realize -1 would work also, but this is for a different context.

Comment: You could adjust the measure to be `75% = MAXX(FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), [Cumulative Cost]  <= 0.75 * SUM(Budget[Budget])),
               'Calendar'[Week])`